# uridecodebin not found in installed gstreamer1.0

Tags: uri, gstreamer

I am trying the examples from gstreamer SDC docs.

In particular  [this page](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-components-uridecodebin.html), suggest to use URIDecodebin like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///test.ogg ! ! audioconvert \
  ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

But I get this error immediately:

```
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "uridecodebin".
```

I followed [this installation instruction](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Linux) for Ubuntu.

I got this stuff installed already:

```
i  gstreamer1.0-alsa - GStreamer plugin for ALSA
i  gstreamer1.0-clutter - Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
i  gstreamer1.0-libav - libav plugin for GStreamer
i  gstreamer1.0-nice - ICE library (GStreamer plugin)
i  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad - GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
i  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad - GStreamer faad plugin from the "bad" set
i  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers - GStreamer videoparsers plugin from the "bad" set
i  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base - GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
i  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps - GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
i  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good - GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
i  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly - GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
i  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio - GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
i  gstreamer1.0-tools - Tools for use with GStreamer
i  gstreamer1.0-x    - GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
i  libgstreamer1.0-0 - Core GStreamer libraries and elements
i  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 - Core GStreamer libraries and elements
i  phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 - transitional package
```

How to get `uridecodebin` installed? Or is it deprecated and should be ignored?

Comment: you have two consecutive ! ! in your pipe..

Comment: somebody (maybe you) submited [bug in docs](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=756630)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your pipe

- one is the wrong path file:///test.ogg (you need to have absolute path),
- the part with two ! ! with no element in the middle..

This is working for me (expecting you will execute from the location of test.ogg):

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file://`pwd`/test.ogg ! audioconvert !  audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

uridecodebin is certainly not deprecated.. 
you can check if you have it with command:

`gst-inspect-1.0 uridecodebin` - shell output details about the element